# How do I open Xara Extreme files on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: convert

I have a couple of files made with Xara extreme (.xar) and I want to open them on Ubuntu 15.10 but Xara exteme is not available anymore on the repositories.

How do I open this files?

Comment: It not being in the repositories does not mean you can not install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Open Source version of Xara Xtreme known as 'Xara Extreme for Linux' or Xaralx. This installs on Trusty Tahr as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install xaralx  xaralx-examples xaralx-svg
```

And in tests on my Trusty Tahr system this both imports and exports .xar files. Screenshot below demonstrating this:

[image]

Interestingly enough while `xaralx` is available and works beautifully under Trusty Tahr it does not appear to be available in either Wily or the upcoming Xenial...

**References:**

- Wikipedia: [Xara Xtreme LX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xara_Xtreme_LX)
- [Edit Images In Linux With Xara Extreme](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/09/edit-images-in-linux-with-xara-extreme.html)

Comment: I tried but I'm using 15.10. Even downloaded the tar file from http://xaraxtreme.org/download.html but no luck running it. Is there another way?

Comment: I end up installing it on a 14.04 machine and converted the files to png.

Comment: Indeed, looks like Wily and xenial do not have xaralx, hopefully some keen person with a PPA will take up the challenge :)